# Direct Proof that Continuous Functions Satisfy Epsilon-Delta Condition

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If we define a continuous real function $f: M \to R$ as one that preserves sequential convergence:
$$
 (x_n)\to p \Rightarrow f(x_n) \to f(p), \tag{1}
$$
then to show that this definition is equivalent to the epsilon-delta condition,
$$
\forall p \forall \epsilon \exists \delta: x \in V_{\delta}(p) \Rightarrow f(x) \in V_{\epsilon}(f(p)), \tag{2}
$$
my textbooks use use a proof by contradiction in which they derive a convergent sequence that does not converge under the mapping.

Question: Is it possible to have a direct proof of $(1) \to (2)$?

Thought: I think to directly show that $(1) \to (2)$, we will have to show that every element of M is an element of at least a sequence in $M$, i.e., the union of the elements of all the sequences in $M$ is $M$.

Comment: It's worth noting that [sequential continuity can be weaker than continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1457267/sequential-continuity-does-not-imply-continuity) in a general topological space. I'm guessing $M$ is a metric space?