# Does a continuous map send a convergent sequence to a convergent sequence?

Tags: general-topology

Consider topological spaces $(S,\,{\cal{T}})\,$, $(S^{\,\prime},\,{\cal{T}}^{\,\prime})\;$ and a continuous map $F: S\longrightarrow S^{\,\prime}$.

The limit of a sequence $\{x_n\}$ is a point $x\in S$, every neighbourhood of which contains all the points of the sequence, except at most finitely many of them.

1. My understanding is that if $\{F(x_n)\}$ is convergent then  $\{x_n\}$ is convergent, provided $F$ is continuous.
   Please correct me if I am wrong.
2. Would the reverse statement be correct, that a continuous map sends a convergent sequence to a convergent one? I suspect, it won't, unless $F$ is an open function, i.e., maps open sets to open sets. But I am not sure...

Comment: Continuity always implies sequential continuity but not the converse.

Comment: Souav Ghosh  By sequentil continuity, do you imply that the *preimage* converges? Also, if you could shape your comment into an answer, that would give me an opportinity to accept it, so you get a full credit in points.

Comment: $x_n\to x\implies f(x_n) \to f(x) $

Comment: @SouravGhosh How to prove this? Is a reverse statement correct also?

Comment: Suppose $F:S\to S'$ continuous and $s_n\to s $ in $(S, \tau) $ . Then show that $F(s_n) \to F(s) $ in $(S', \tau') $

Comment: @SouravGhosh This is exactly the subject of my question: how to prove that $F(x_n) \longrightarrow F(x)$ ?

Comment: For converse, take $\textrm{Id}:(\Bbb{R}, \tau_{\textrm{cocountable}}) \to(\Bbb{R}, \tau_{\textrm{euclidean}}) $

Comment: @SouravGhosh So your answer to my 2nd question is negative, correct? How about my 1st question? Not being a mathematician, I don't know what cocountable is. A more detailed answer understandable to a layman would be most appreciated.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2343423/977780) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1457319/977780).

Comment: "the preimage $\{x_n\}$ of a converging sequence $\{F(x_n)\}$" makes no sense, unless $F$ is invertible. But I suppose what you mean to ask in part (i) is, if $(F(x_n))$ converges, does $(x_n)$ necessarily converge?

Comment: @TonyK Yes, this is what I wanted to ask. Corrected my question. Thank you.

Comment: A constant map is always continuous, and sends every sequence to a (trivial) convergent sequence.